# MiKTeX Installation Fails with "Executed process did not succeed"

Tags: miktex, windows

I cannot get MiKTeX 2.9.6069 to install on Windows 10 Home 64-bit.

Here is the failure message from my last attempt, using the 32-bit installer with no option changes:

> The operation could not be completed for the following reason:
>
> The executed process did not succeed.
>
> Details: fileName="C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe",
>   arguments="--common-install="C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
>   --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin
>   --log-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose", exitCode="1"

Here is the last bit of the installation log, from my first attempt this session with the 64-bit installer, and some option changes such as A4 --> Letter, Always auto-load packages, etc.:

> installed 2989 package definition files
>
> visiting repository C:\Users\x2\AppData\Local\Temp\mik10126...
>
> repository type: local package repository
>
> loading lightweight database...
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:    --common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9: unknown option  The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>
> C:/Users/x2/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log  You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
>
> Error: The executed process did not succeed.

Here's the contents of the `.log`-file the above references:

> 2016-08-29 20:15:32,192-0700 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6050 (MiKTeX 2.9)
>
> 2016-08-29 20:15:32,207-0700 FATAL initexmf - --common-install=C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9: unknown option
>
> 2016-08-29 20:43:35,521-0700 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6050 (MiKTeX 2.9)
>
> 2016-08-29 20:43:35,537-0700 FATAL initexmf - --common-install=C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9: unknown option
>
> 2016-08-29 20:58:24,381-0700 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6050 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
>
> 2016-08-29 20:58:24,412-0700 FATAL initexmf - --common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9: unknown option
>
> 2016-09-11 18:29:25,957-0700 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6050 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
>
> 2016-09-11 18:29:25,973-0700 FATAL initexmf - --common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9: unknown option

I've tried numerous times in different sessions (i.e. span of time and numerous restarts between); various option combos; deleted Program Files folders, tried again; run as administrator and not.

I do find it rather disturbing that the slashes do not seem to be consistent in the URIs. That's a sure way to make things not work, from my limited programming experience. But I see that has been the case in most of the instances of failed installations since 2013, at least. If it were the problem, I would hope it would've gotten fixed by now. So not likely the problem?

Comment: The slashes/backslashes are not a problem. But it looks as if the quotes are missing around the path name -- imho the option should be e.g. `--common-install="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"`. Without the quotes the spaces in the path leads to errors. This looks like a bug to me and you should make a report.  You could also try to install miktex "only for you" in a folder without spaces.

Comment: Just tried only for me, to a folder without spaces and periods, all the services and processes seeming to pertain to PDFs, text editing, etc. turned off, and antivirus turned off. Still no go.

Comment: You might not have the user rights you need. Try running the MiKTeX Package Manager(Admin) option.

Comment: The problem is with the rights to Program Files.
You can create, for example, the directory C:\Prog and install without problems for all users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit late to this, but finally managed to solve this "unknown option" issue after hours of tinkering with the setup options (even to the extent of reformatting Windows) but to no avail.

Apparently the initexmf.exe file does not like being renamed. According to a bug report with this issue: [#2515 basic-miktex installer fails if the executable is renamed](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2515/), it checks for the name of the invoker and only makes available certain options if the name matches.

Moral of the story: **Don't rename the setup file.**

Example: If it is "basic-miktex-2.9.6161-x64.exe", then **leave it as it is**. This should resolve the "unknown option" issue.

Comment: Renaming installation files is definitely what I do, and not renaming it made MikTex install. Good job sleuthing that one out!

Comment: Shit... spend hours on this. I had not even renamed it myself, but turned out I had already once downloaded it before, so windows put a (1) behind the name...

Answer (score 7):

I tried finding and executing `initexmf.exe`.  It was where the window said it was.

I got this additional information by running it as Administrator:

> fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe",
>   exitCode="1"   Option -admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX
>   setup.
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the
>   following reason:
>
> ```
> Option -admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.
> ```
>
> Error: The executed process did not succeed.

Apparently there is a logical error in the setup utility `initexmf.exe` that prevents it from completing an install of build 2.9.6942 for All Users, i.e. in C`:\Programs`.  From Jorge Martinez' post, it can install for a single user.

I first ran into the problem by running MiKTeX Update (Admin) which fails.  Re-running this update utility eventually results in non-functional MiKTeX including deleted Update utilities.

I deleted all MiKTeX folders in `C:\Programs` and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local` and ran the installation for MiKTeX build 2.9.6161, which I had saved from the original installation.  This installer completed successfully and my TeXnicCenter 2.02 is fully functional again.  I'll update when another build of MiKTeX appears and a check here shows that it works for All Users.

Comment: Likewise.  However, I was installing my installation onto another partition that has my other build utilities.

Comment: Lately still not fixed yet. I ran in the same situation, but my case was rejected on miktex. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/334

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem installing MiKTeX on Windows ("The executed process did not succeed").

I solved it by saving the installation file directly under C:
and then run it from there, the installation was then successful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Good way to circumvent the problem of spaces in `Program Files`!

Comment: This solution did not help

Answer (score 1):

You can try to kill all pdf viewer processes (Adobe, Sumatra, etc.) and try to run the MiKTeX installation again.

I had the similar problem as you, and making sure that Adobe Reader is not running during the MiKTeX installation helped in my case. I also closed Word, Notepad and every other text processing program, just in case.

Comment: Unsuccessful as yet. Closed anything pertaining to PDFs, text processing, etc. as well as security software. I even tried installing in safe mode. Went through and cleared out any reference to MikTex in the registry. Same failure all-round.

Comment: I have Adobe CC installed; Bullzip PDF Printer; Evernote; EditPad Pro; Google Drive. No MS Office whatsoever. Those are the bulk of what seem pertinent. I wonder if Bullzip might be throwing it off, but I haven't gone about uninstalling it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and resolving it by running the installer (original name) from C:\ as administrator did not work.

Installation was successful after closing all applications (including MS office, Firefox, and the Adobe Updater from Task Manager as it was the only remaining Adobe process). I then installed as described above, but further chose "install for all users" and "ask me first" pertaining to auto-installing missing packages. These were the installer defaults, whereas before I chose "for only this user" and "install missing packages on the fly". I cannot confirm if all of these steps are necessary, I'm not touching my working installation anymore :)

MiKTeX: basic-miktex-2.9.6753-x64.exe
platform: Windows 7

Comment: Thanks @Bart, this was the solution that worked for me... specifically a restart, saving the .exe to my C:Program Files directory, and allowing MikTex to choose all defaults. In my case the defaults were to save the program to my personal directory. Then it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem running the setup as administrator, previously I deleted all files in the created folder (Miktex). Important thing: I run the setup as administrator and I installed the BASIC Miktex and it seems to work, right now I'm installing all the extra libraries or whatever are needed. Hope it's usefull

Answer (score 0):

1. I renamed the file *basic-miktex-21.6-x64.exe* to *miktex-portable.exe*
2. Restarted computer
3. After reboot did not start any application
4. I signed as administrator and tried to install, but it did not work
5. Then I turned myself to user as shown in the picture and tried to install again in the desktop: D:\Desktop

[image: user]

6. The portable version has been installed sucefully