# MiKTeX Update directly after Installation makes it not usable

Tags: miktex, installing, windows, miktex-update

as the title says, the update that MiKTeX want to do directly after installation makes it unusable.

1. I want to install MiKTeX on my Windows 10 that is in a DOM of my company.
2. Link for installation: https://miktex.org/download
3. The installation is just on the local user.
4. Installation works fine.
5. If I force MiKTeX not to do the Updates, I can compile a standard .tex-Document without problems. But only one package for each compilation process is installed. So I had to start the compiling about 5 times to have the basic-packages.
6. If I do the 102 Updates that MiKTeX recommends directly after installation (or later after trying step 5), I get an error message. The installation seems to run completely through, but nevertheless the error is appearing:
   [image: Error after Update]
7. If I click on yes I get this message: `The executed procress did not succeed.` and `fileName="C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-fc-cache.exe", exitCode="1"`
   [image: Errof after Update if I click on "yes"]
8. The Copy Info gives me the follwing text:

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
ReportDate: 2021-03-29 14:04:13
CurrentVersion: 21.2
SetupDate: 2021-03-29 14:02:00
SetupVersion: 21.2
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 7a7e645 / 2021-02-20 10:38:14
OS: Windows 10 Education, 64-bit, build 18363
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: no
LastUpdateCheck: 2021-03-29 14:02:53
LastUpdate: 2021-03-29 14:03:35
LastUpdateDb: 2021-03-29 14:02:51
SystemAdmin: no
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
Root1: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Root2: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserConfig: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
UserData: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
Invokers: non-existing/cmd

ERROR DETAILS
Program: miktex-fc-cache.exe
Error: The executed process did not succeed.
Details: 
  fileName: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-fc-cache.exe
  exitCode: 1
```

9. After this failed update, MiKTeX will no longer show any updates or so. It just says: "No new Updates availabe".
10. But if I now try to compile any LaTeX-document (e.g. in TeXMaker or TeXworks), I get this error message: `Die Ausführung des Codes kann nicht fortgesetzt werden, da MiKTeX210200-png.dll nicht gefunden wurde. Durch eine Neuinstallation des Programms kann das Problem möglicherweise behoben werden.` or `The execution of the code cannot continue because MiKTeX210200-png.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem.` (translated to English)
    [image: Die Ausführung des Codes kann nicht fortgesetzt werden, da MiKTeX210200-png.dll nicht gefunden wurde. Durch eine Neuinstallation des Programms kann das Problem möglicherweise behoben werden.]
11. I could get a kind of log-file out of this problem with "TeXworks". Is says the following:

```
2021-03-29 15:04:02,156+0200 INFO  texify - this process (18644) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe --pdf --synctex=1 --clean Beispiel.tex
2021-03-29 15:04:02,204+0200 INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex --synctex=1 C:/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads\Beispiel.tex
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 ERROR texify.core - Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 ERROR texify.core - Function: CopyFileW
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 ERROR texify.core - Result: 2
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 ERROR texify.core - Data: existing="Beispiel.log", path="C:/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads\Beispiel.log"
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 ERROR texify.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:390
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify.core - TeX engine failed for some reason.
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify.core - Data: 
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify.core - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1529
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason.
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify - Info: 
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2021-03-29 15:04:02,248+0200 FATAL texify - Line: 1529
```

12. I reinstalled the MiKTeX several times. And tired also:

- Installing as local admin
- Installing with the option, that new packages will install without asking

So. Has somebody an idea? After 4 h I could not solve the problem, and am now a bit desperate. I also could not find the solution in the www so far.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a related question that might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329125/miktex-installation-fails-with-executed-process-did-not-succeed Also, some more googling suggests that this may be related to non-ASCII characters in the Windows username. You censored that (sensibly), so I can't say if this is applicable, but it may be worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I did not renamed the setup file. It is "basic-miktex-21.2-x64.exe". In my usernames are only ASCII-characters. Hm. So this could not be the problem. Also the problem seems only to appear after the "Update"-process. So before everything is fine. I could compile. But afterwards the update-process somehow ruins everything.

Comment: the fc-cache error could mean that you have some fonts that confuses fc-cache, but you are in the wrong place here to solve this: Open an issue at the miktex github.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would not expect that a font could confuse the Update-process. But I could make an issue in the miktex-github. thats a good idea. Another account, jeah^^